# How can I stop the clock on a VirtualBox guest OS install of Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, networking, ubuntu, virtualbox, virtual-machine

I am running Virtualbox 4.3.30 (r 101601) on an Ubuntu 14.04 host and the guest OS is Windows 7 64.

Would like to stop the clock in the guest while it is not running. i.e. switch on the `TSCTiedToExecution` feature.

I have tried following all available instructions to do this but have not achieved the desired results.

What I have tried is this:

In host terminal:

```
$ VBoxManage setextradata "Win7" "VBoxInternal/TM/TSCTiedToExecution" 1

$ VBoxManage setextradata "Win7" "VBoxInternal/Devices/VMMDev/0/Config/GetHostTimeDisabled" 1
```

In guest in regedit:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\VBoxService\ImagePath
```

set to:

```
system32\VBoxService.exe --disable-timesync
```

Also in guest have turned off internet time synchronisation in the clock control panel.
Have also switched off the nat adapter.

None of the above works. The guest date & time are always the same as the host. Any suggestions?

Sometimes the suggestions available are not clear on what actions should be in guest/host. Is this part of the problem?